# need to convert object into array

Tags: javascript

```
const obj = {
  obj1: [{
    name: 'Max',
    age: 25
  }]
}

Object.values(obj).map(obj => console.log(obj.obj1.name))
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. I need to get that name

Comment: Some minor debugging (`console.log(obj)`) would have told you the problem.

Comment: What should I do to get the name?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What are you trying to convert to an array?

Comment: const obj = {
  obj1: {
    name: [{first: "Max'}]',
    age: 25
  }
}

Object.values(obj).map(obj => console.log(obj.obj1.name))

Comment: this is my code and I need to map through this to get name

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to loop through the object values, using forEach instead of the map is a good idea. Map returns a new array but forEach doesn't. Also, Object.values() will return an array of all the values in the object(each value is an array of objects in this case). Therefore, using 2 forEach loops makes the task easier.

```js
const obj = {
  obj1: [{
    name: 'Max',
    age: 25
  }],
  obj2: [{
    name: 'Min',
    age: 26
  }]
}

Object.values(obj).forEach(mainObj => mainObj.forEach(obj => console.log(obj.name )))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the wrong key. Your object has a key obj1 which is an array. You have to loop through that array as well.

```js
const obj = {
  obj1: [{
    name: 'Max',
    age: 25
  }],
  obj2: [{
    name: 'Min',
    age: 24
  }]
}

var objectValuesArr = Object.values(obj)
var particularObj = objectValuesArr.map(obj => obj.forEach(obj => console.log(obj.name)))
```